# Charges in receiving antenna and polarization if alternating current is changed to stay high

Tags: electromagnetism, radio

A dipole antenna receiver placed in parallel to a dipole antenna transmitter will have a current induced in the opposite direction to the current in the transmitter. This causes charges (electrons and holes) to move to opposite ends of the antenna. If the signal from the transmitter is an alternating current, and the signal then during one sine wave stays at the peak of one half period, and stays high, will the charges in the receiving antenna remain polarized?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking does a conductor become polarised in the presence of a static electric field? If so the answer is yes.

For your signal to stay at the peak it is no longer AC so your question is a little confusing.

Comment: Well, I'm asking, considering basic electromagnetic transmission of signals, and over large distances, the "rule of thumb" is usually that electromagnetic waves are radiated when current changes, so that the charged particles either accelerate or decelerate. That is the context of why I ask what happens when an AC current changes to stay high (and becomes DC, or analogously when DC first starts up). Will the polarization that was induced, relax as the AC stops changing (and becomes DC), or will it remain (in the image above, remain as it was at the peak and as is shown)?

Comment: When your current becomes DC your transmitting antenna no longer radiates. So any electric field due to charge build up (as in your image) will be static, and so falls off as 1/r^2 rather than 1/r in the case of radiated EM wave. So the effect on your receive antenna will be significantly less

Comment: OK thanks. So the polarized charges should move back towards original position again, from electrostatic repulsion/attraction within receiving dipole antenna, once the AC changes to remain high and becomes DC. And, I guess that is easily measurable.

Comment: Essentially yes. It all depends on how far away your antennas are from eachother

Comment: They are far away as normal distances for transmission. So pretty far away.

Comment: Then yes it will be as you said.

Comment: Do you by any chance know any good source where I can see the oscilloscope of a receiving dipole, as DC current into a transmitter charges up (the transient that is radiating), & notice that it will flow backwards once the DC reaches its steady-state? Not because I in any way doubt the rule, I just like to see things practically. I'm pretty good at circuit design, I can design advanced digital circuits, but I am much less experienced with electromagnetic radiation based systems. I also have harder time finding good simulation software for that (Falstad is great for circuits, I mostly use it).

Comment: CST studio is good simulation software that would allow you to do this though it can be expensive. Otherwise if you can get hold of an oscilloscope you could easily make up your own dipoles and test it yourself